# keyboard ENTER key dont work for tlf text input?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, keyboard, tlf

i have a tlf text input in stage,i want dispatch ahndler for this object when enter key in press, but i can't do this

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.Sprite;
tlf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (event.keyCode = Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        trace('enter key is detect');
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator '=' is for assignation, not comparison. The EQUAL TO operator is '=='. So, in your code:

```
 if (event.keyCode = Keyboard.ENTER)
```

should be:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
```

Assuming you have a text input on the stage, and it's called 'tlf', this will work:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.Sprite;

tlf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,key_down_handler);

function key_down_handler(ev:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (ev.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        trace('enter key!!!!');
    }
}
```

One advice: try to give your variables and functions more meaningful names, for example instead of just 'tlf', if it's an input textfield: '**tlf_input_text'** and instead of just 'handler': '**key_down_handler**' or something like this. It will help others (and yourself, in the long run) to read and understand your code.

Comment: Also, if testing in the Flash IDE ensure that keyboard shortcuts are disabled to ensure all the key presses are caught by the SWF.

Comment: danii tlf handle event a bit difrrent

Answer (score 1):

TLFText handles the Enter Key differently than the classic text. For TLF use this:

```
tlf.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, textInputHandler);

function textInputHandler(evt:TextEvent):void {
    if (evt.text=="\r") {
        trace('THE ENTER KEY WORKS NOW');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced the same issue.

The best way to solve it for me, was to add (useCapture=true) to the event listener.

So this:
`tlf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);`

Becomes this:
`tlf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler,true);`

I don't believe the 2 answers previously provided are satisfactory. 
One wants the coder to stop using TLF, the other wants him to stop using KeyboardEvent.

*Reference:*
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/826424